# DecimalFormat - can it handle phone numbers, SSNs, etc.?

Tags: java, decimalformat

I've found the following with unexpected results:

```
format           number          result            expected
"000-00-0000"    123456789L      "123456789--"     "123-45-6789"
"(###)###-####"  1234567890L     "(1234567890)-"   "(123)456-7890"
"_($* "-"_)"     0               " $ \t- 0"         " $ \t- "
```

Can it not handle non-number formats like phone numbers, social security numbers, etc?

Comment: For the second case, did you mix result and expected?

Comment: @YassinHajaj - sorry, yes. Third one too. Fixing it now. thanks

Answer (score 0):

It could probably be hacked to do so, but it's has not been *created* for this purposes.
These kind of tasks could be taken up by regular expressions and be far more effective and expressive.

The first example could be simplified to the following

```
String regex = "^(\\d{3})(\\d{2})(\\d{4})$";
String input = 123456789L + "";

System.out.println(input.replaceAll(regex, "$1-$2-$3")); // 123-45-6789
```

The second one to the following

```
String regex = "^(\\d{3})(\\d{3})(\\d{4})$";
String input = 1234567890L + "";

System.out.println(input.replaceAll(regex, "($1)$2-$3")); // (123)456-7890
```

And so on...